# jQuery: this dentro de llamada AJaX

Tags: jquery, css

En mi web, los mensajes personales sin leer aparecen en color rojo y los leídos, en azul.

He creado un script jQuery para que al hacer clic en un mensaje no leído, pase a leído en la BD (de 0 a 1) y cambie de color mediante un cambio en las clases CSS:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.mensaje-no-leido').click(function()
    {
        var idMensaje = $(this).data('id-mensaje');

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST', url: '../ajax_marcar_leidos.php', data: {id_mensaje: idMensaje},
            success: function(respuesta) 
            {
                if(respuesta == 1) $(this).removeClass('mensaje-no-leido').addClass('mensaje-leido');
                else swal('Vaya...', 'Sabemos que lo querías marcar como leído, pero algo ha fallado...', 'error', {button: false});
            },
            error: function() 
            {
                swal('Vaya...', 'Sabemos que lo querías marcar como leído, pero algo ha fallado...', 'error', {button: false});
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Sin embargo, `$(this).removeClass('mensaje-no-leido').addClass('mensaje-leido');` sólo funciona fuera de la llamada AJaX, pero no quiero que se cambie el color simplemente con hacer clic, sino tras recibir la confirmación desde la BD de que se ha ejecutado el `UPDATE`.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Lo más fácil: guarda el $(this) en una variable, por ejemplo: `const elemClicked = $(this);`, y luego simplemente accede a `elemClicked`

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que las funciones que tienes en la respuesta del ajax, tiene su propio scope y no hereda la del padre.

Puedes declarar las funciones como función flecha, esto te permitirá usar el atributo scoped del padre que es en este caso es:

```
$('.mensaje-no-leido').click(function()
```

El Código quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
$(function()
{
    $('.mensaje-no-leido').click(function()
    {
        var idMensaje = $(this).data('id-mensaje');

        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST', url: '../ajax_marcar_leidos.php', data: {id_mensaje: idMensaje},
            success: (respuesta) =>
            {
                if(respuesta == 1) $(this).removeClass('mensaje-no-leido').addClass('mensaje-leido');
                else swal('Vaya...', 'Sabemos que lo querías marcar como leído, pero algo ha fallado...', 'error', {button: false});
            },
            error: () =>
            {
                swal('Vaya...', 'Sabemos que lo querías marcar como leído, pero algo ha fallado...', 'error', {button: false});
            }
        })
    });
});
```